# Can somebody elaborate whose public key and signature is included in a transcation in blockchain?

Tags: hash, blockchain, digital-signature, public-key-encryption, cryptocurrency

[Transaction connected through other transcations**strong text**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1qn7.png)

i am not able to understand exactly about that hash box in the above image ,what it contains and whether the public key belongs to that transcation owner or else the recievers public key .
Please explain this stuff .

Answer (score 0):

Owner (n-1) give a signature on a hash by using it's private key on block (n) where the hash is the combination of previous hash plus Owner (n)'s public key & to verify the signature on block n, you have to use Owner (n-1)'s public key.